# Formula checkbox field with an additional "and"

Tags: formula, formula-field

Trying to create a formula checkbox field which uses the AND( function, but also has a second AND( statement. This is what I have below, but am receiving errors. Everything at the beginning is correct and working until my second "AND(." To summarize, the box should be checked if referred to OF equals false or referred to OF = true and Reason for OF Referral = "Parallel Process."

```
AND(    
    RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Standard',
    Paused__c = false,
    Referred_to_OF__c = false,
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "RFA"),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "CFC"),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "E-Tran"),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Started"),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "HO"),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "handoff"),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Audit"),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "prequal"),
        ISPICKVAL(StageName, "PQ"),
        AND(
            Referred_to_OF__c = true,
            ISPICKVAL(Reason_for_OF_referral__c, "Parallel Process"),
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ISPICKVAL(Reason_for_OF_referral__c, "Parallel Process"),
```

I don't think that comma should be there at the end as it's the last parameter you're providing to your AND operator.

Comment: that was it!! Thank you!

Comment: @JennaOdom If your problem has been resolved, you should upvote helpful answers (once you get enough reputation) and mark the one that helped you the most (or is the most correct) as the accepted answer. Doing so signals to the community that you don't need more help, signals to others (coming from google) that an answer is likely to be correct, and gives both you and the answerer reputation points. You don't _need_ to do this, but it is a core part of the stackexchange culture.